# Set different pricing attributes for each product

Tags: commerce

here is the thing:
 On my drupal commerce site I added a term reference field 'sizes' to line item, and make it to be an attribute on 'add to cart' form.
 Also I added a field collection in to my product, wich has two fields: Margin(price) and size(term reference). So when I add some product I can choose a size and some extra margin to price.
 What I want to do is when user add product to cart he chose some size, this size would compare with a size in field collection and the price for this item will update relatively to margin field collection field.
 Anyone have any idea how can I do this?
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Neograph734, but it's not exectly what I tryed to do.
Maybe it isn't a proper way to do it but I solve this problem using custom _add_to_cart_form_submit() function and hook_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh().
So it looks something like this (maybe it will help someone):

```
function custom_add_to_cart_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  // line item field_size_pick
  $line_item = $form_state['line_item'];

  $field_size_pick = field_get_items('commerce_line_item', $line_item, 'field_size_pick');
  $size_pick = $field_size_pick[0]['tid'];

  //get product
  $product_id = $form_state['values']['product_id'];
  $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);

  //fc sizes
  $field_fc_product_sizes = field_get_items('commerce_product', $product, 'field_fc_product_sizes');
  foreach ($field_fc_product_sizes as $key => $value) {
    $item_id = $value['value'];
    $fc_item = field_collection_item_load($item_id);

    $field_fc_size = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $fc_item, 'field_fc_size');
    $size = $field_fc_size[0]['tid'];

    if ($size == $size_pick) {
      $field_fc_margin = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $fc_item, 'field_fc_margin');
      $margin = $field_fc_margin[0]['amount'];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isset($margin)) {
    $commerce_unit_price = field_get_items('commerce_line_item', $line_item, 'commerce_unit_price');
    $price = $commerce_unit_price[0]['amount'];
    $price += $margin;

    $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
    $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->set($price);
    $line_item_wrapper->save();
    commerce_line_item_rebase_unit_price($line_item_wrapper->value());
    commerce_line_item_save($line_item_wrapper->value());
  }

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function custom_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh($line_item, $order_wrapper) {

  $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);

  $field_size_pick = $line_item_wrapper->field_size_pick->value();
  $size_pick = $field_size_pick[0]->tid;

  $field_fc_product_sizes = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_fc_product_sizes->value();
  foreach ($field_fc_product_sizes as $key => $fc_item) {
    $field_fc_size = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $fc_item, 'field_fc_size');
    $fc_size = $field_fc_size[0]['tid'];

    if ($size_pick == $fc_size) {
      $field_fc_margin = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $fc_item, 'field_fc_margin');
      $fc_margin = $field_fc_margin[0]['amount'];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isset($fc_margin)) {
    $price = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value();
    $price += $fc_margin;
    $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->set($price);
    $line_item_wrapper->save();

    commerce_line_item_rebase_unit_price($line_item_wrapper->value());
    commerce_line_item_save($line_item_wrapper->value());
  }
  $order_wrapper->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In drupal commerce this goes by the name of product variants. There is quite some information on it, but this article from Drupal commerce should get you started: https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations